# My Wordpress site is not on the root of my website. How do I put it on the root while still keeping my wp-admin and site working?

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, ftp-client

My WP site is hidden in my ftp at public_html/folder1/public_html/folder2/

In order to access my site on the web, I need to go to mywebsite .com /public_html/folder2

How do I make it so I can simply go to mywebsite .com and see my wordpress site?

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting within Wordpress which allows you to control where it publishes to and it can be different to the installation directory.  I've included a screenshot below of where the setting is.

[image]

The Wordpress Codex provides their own advice on how to achieve it:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: I changed my site URL name and wordpress home URL in Wp admin panel. Then my site went down. I moved the files to my root and then edited wp-config to change site url and home url to my site "example.com"... Still not working and my client is mad

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the Wordpress Codex?

I run a Wordpress install with a different publishing location and haven't experienced any issues, however, I set it up that way from the beginning, as opposed to moving it later.